# Why do I get a warning of "unknown class" in VisualCode when using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpmailer

I am struggling to understand why I get this warning in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

I have implemented som mailing functionality for my website (e.g. when mailing confirmation requests or newsletters). I am using the PHPMailer library for this. The code works perfectly, but I get the warning in the file `mailer.php` in Visual Studio Code.

Here's the first lines of `mailer.php` where I reference to PHPMailer files:

```
// mailer.php - first lines of code
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once("PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
require_once("PHPMailer/src/Exception.php");
require_once("PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");

//    ... etc ...
```

The PHPMailer code is stored in the subfolder `PHPMailer/`.

The lines where the warning appears looks like this:

```
function mailer_send($to, $subject, $message) : bool  {
    // ... stripped code ...

    // line 84 below:
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
                ~~~~~~~~~ (<- warning mark in Visual Studio Code)

    // ... stripped code ...

    // line 102 below:
    $mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
                     ~~~~~~~~~ (<- warning mark in Visual Studio Code)
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code, or is my Visual Studio Code reacting badly for some reason? I don't get any errors or warnings when executing the code, and everything works as expected. But I wonder if I can do something to remove the warning message?

Comment: Honestly if it works, why bother? how did you install the PHPMailer, i mean did you use composer?

Comment: @Adi Well, I guess that I'm easily annoyed when things aren't perfect ;) . I have simply unpacked the PHPMailer code package in my files folder on localhost, and then it is published to a web hotel service (one.com). No composer has been used

Comment: That message must come from a third-party extension. Do you know which one it can be?

Comment: In any case, if you are not using Composer or PSR-4, many PHP extensions will not be able to identify third-party libraries correctly if they aren't smart enough to follow arbitrary `require_once` statements.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `use` line after the class is actually included with the `require_once()` lines?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks! That made me investigate the different extensions that were activated. I found out that the problem was found in Devsense's PHP extension. I wrote an answer to describe it more in detail

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with an answer myself, and want to publish my solution here in case somebody else encounters the same problem.

It is the PHP Extension from Devsense that didn't manage to parse the code completely and therefore came up with a warning.

I found out that this could be managed by modifying some of the settings in the PHP extension. The following should be added to `settings.json`:

```
"php.problems.exclude": {
    "mailer.php" : [413],
},
```

This tells the extension to exclude the 413 warning from mailer.php. BUT! It's worth mentioning that this will also exclude relevant warnings as well, i.e. if you misspell the class `$mail = new PHPMaler()`, it won't warn you for your mistake... and the execution will probably fail.

Comment: It might be worth to change the way you load libraries and use Composer. It's the industry standard and the extension is likely to recognise the classes that way.